# Putting Logic in the view or in the helper - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, code-cleanup

I'm having some difficulties in drawing the lines between putting code in the view or putting it in the helper.

For example this is code that I put in the view:

```
<div id="top-columns">
  <!-- large-3 columns -->
  <% if @show_interest_group %>
  <% rows_for_groups(@interest_groups).each do |groups| %>
    <div class="row">
      <% groups.each do |group| %>
        <div class="<%= css_class_for_groups(groups)%> interestgroupBlock">
          <article>
            <%= link_to '', jobs_path(:category => group.sap_id), :class => "plusSign"%>
            <h3 class="headingMedium">
              <%= group.title %>
            </h3>
            <figure>
              <%= image_tag group.image_url, :alt => group.alt %>
            </figure>
            <p class=""><%= group.body %></p>
            <p class="more"><%= link_to t("home.jobs.view_link"), jobs_path(:category => group.sap_id)%></p>
          </article>
      </div>
  <% end %>
  </div>





  <% if @questionnaires.present? %>
  <%= render_numbered_header(ApplyField.surveys_title) %>
            <div class="collapsable">
  <fieldset>
  <div class="large-12 columns">
    <% @questionnaires.each_with_index do |questionnaire,i| %>

      <h3> <strong><%= questionnaire["QUESTIONNAIRE_NAME"] %></strong></h3>
      <p><%= questionnaire["QUESTIONNAIRE_DESCRIPTION"] %></p>
      <% questionnaire["QUESTIONS"].collect{|q| q["QUESTION"]}.each do |question| %>

      <%= render_question(question, {"data-template_id" =>questionnaire["QUESTIONNAIRE_TEMPLATE_ID"]}, params[:surveys]) %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %></div></div></fieldset>
  <% end -%>
  <% end %>
```

So for clean programming, do I have the refactor this code and put it in a helper or am I allowed to  write code like this.

Answer (score 0):

You are allowed to use such a code in a view , but you do not want to use the code repitively that is **remain DRY**

u can definitely put piece of code in a helper (name of file should be _make_table.html.erb in the same directory or different (start with _) )

and can put the line in the main form

`<%= render :partial => "make_table", :locals => {:user => user}%>`

Comment: What do you mean by code repetitively? Do you mean Loops?

Comment: No if any other view contains the same code , then you dont need to repeat yourself , just put it in a helper and use.